# psql column doesn't exist but it does

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select a single column in my data table using raw SQL in a postgresql database from the psql command line.  I am getting an error message that says the column does not exist.  Then it gives me a hint to use the exact column that I referenced in the select statement.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactionDate FROM insider_app_ownershipdocument;
```

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR:  column insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactiondate does not exist
SELECT insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactionDate FROM in...
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactionDate".
```

I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Capitalization- transactiondate vs transactionDate?

Comment: I tried that one

Comment: if you don't call the `insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactionDate`  just `transactiondate` what happen?

Answer (score 3):

(Postgres) SQL converts names automatically to lower case although it support case-sensitive names. So

```
SELECT insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactionDate FROM insider_app_ownershipdocument;
```

will be aquivalent to:

```
SELECT insider_app_ownershipdocument.transactiondate FROM insider_app_ownershipdocument;
```

You should protect the column name with double quotes to avoid this effect:

```
SELECT insider_app_ownershipdocument."transactionDate" FROM insider_app_ownershipdocument;
```

Comment: You mean when creating the table, they put the column name in quotes (`"transactionDate"`), and this forces them to use quotes now everytime on the column name? Have I understood this correctly? If so, they may prefer to rename the column to a mere `transactiondate`.

Comment: No, not exactly. You must quote the name always, if you have chosen a case-sensitive name. This is not very comfortable, so I would avoid case-sensitive names. But that's a matter of taste.